# Any benefits of ZFS over EXT4 for data stream processing on top of HDFS?

Tags: zfs, ext4, hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

I'm working on a data stream processing project in which i will be using Apache Flink and Apache Spark and I want to use HDFS for storage. The development and testing will be done on a single node cluster with multiple physical disks.

I have already checked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/771616/zfs-for-hadoop-cloud-instead-of-ext4) and [this white paper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/sun-unified-storage/documentation/hadoop-on-oracle-adurant-2392150.pdf), but I am not sure on how applicable it is to my scenario, and still confused between using the disks as separate EXT4 volumes with HDFS or creating one pool with ZFS.

I want to know how these 2 options compare in terms of performance and data loss protection, and what would be the recommended approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zfs for Hadoop cloud instead of ext4](https://serverfault.com/questions/771616/zfs-for-hadoop-cloud-instead-of-ext4)

Comment: @JohnMahowald I've seen that question and it refers to the white paper I linked, but my use case is a little different as I mentioned in my question.